# Which the function of this "thing" (photo) in Shimano XTR SL-M952 rear shifter?

Tags: shimano, shifter

Well, I bought this shifters (Shimano XTR SL-M952) and during the cleaning I found this curious detail in the rear shifter body (integrated to the clamp).
What is the purpose or function of this thing?

[image: What is the purpose (or function) of this marked detail? (Shimano XTR SL-M952 rear shifter)]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was a remote shifter available for ST-M952 and SL-M952 and some others of the era, so you could shift from your bar end. It actuated the main shifter via cables and housings. This is a stop for the housing.

Comment: If you are curious like me, google for SL-SS95 images.